# creating CLLocationCoordinate2D on the fly while conforming to MKAnnotation protocol

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, objective-c-protocol

I have `MyClass` that conforms to `MKAnnotation` protocol. according to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation), class is required to implement `coordinate` property which should return `CLLocationCoordinate2D` instance.
My first implementation was like this:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
   return MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(self.details.latitude, self.details.longitude));
}
```

but this did not worked: whenever I call `[self.mapView addAnnotation:instanceOfMyClass];` it just simply wasn't added to the `annotations` array of the `mapView`!

So, the solution for me was to define an instance variable `_coordinate` in `MyClass` and implement protocol conformance like this:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    _coordinate.latitude = self.details.latitude;
    _coordinate.longitude = self.details.longitude;
    return _coordinate;
}
```

which now worked.
So, the question here is WHY it is needed to have an instance variable and creating `CLLocationCoordinate2D` on-the-fly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your self.details.latitude/longitude values already true/valid geographic coordinates?
In that case you should use the `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lon)` function instead of `MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake())` which is wrong.